# UIAlertView. Using otherbutton as a openURL.

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

I want it once the user taps the 'otherbutton' it goes to my link.
But at the moment once the button is pressed it doesn't do anything.

Sorry im on my iPhone so I've used pastebin for the code

http://pastebin.com/fvgk87ih

Thanks alot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Conform your controller class to the UIAlertViewDelegate protocol.

```
@interface MyViewController : UIViewController <UIAlertViewDelegate>
```

Create the alert view with delegate set to self:

```
UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Follow" message:@"me on twitter" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"No" otherButtonTitles:@"Yes", nil];
[alert show];
[alert release];
```

Respond to the delegate method

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView didDismissWithButtonIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {
    if (buttonIndex != [alertView cancelButtonIndex]) {
       // open url
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The `delegate` of your `UIAlertView` must be set to the class (`self` in most cases) that's using it. Make sure your class calling the `UIAlertView` does conform to the `UIAlertViewDelegate` delegate.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the `UIAlertView`'s `delegate` property to `self` instead of `nil` and implement the protocol in the header.

Header File:

```
@interface MyViewController : UIViewController <UIAlertViewDelegate>
```

In addition, check for the `buttonIndex`. Currently, (after performing the above), it will open the URL if *any* button is pressed.

```
- (void)alertView: (UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex: (NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
    if (buttonIndex != [alertView cancelButtonIndex])
    {
       //open url
    }
}
```

Comment: should be if (buttonIndex != [alertView cancelButtonIndex])!!